# How to mimic headful browser in headless mode in puppeteer

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, puppeteer

Am using `Puppeteer` to scrape some websites, the scrapper works fine if it's headful but it doesn't work in `headless`, I think there could be some checks being done for that, my question is, is there away to mimic a `headfull` behavoir while in `headless` mode ?

Comment: Use User Agent, override WebGL Vendor and Renderer by using `page.evaluateOnNewDocument()`, Avoid Detection via `navigator.webdriver` by setting it to `False`

Comment: @Obaskly can you provide example snippets ?

Comment: @Obaskly change that to an answer, so I can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few strategies you can employ to make your Puppeteer script appear more like a regular browser session

- Use User Agent:

```
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
```

- Use [Stealth Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
```

- Spoofing WebGL Vendor and Renderer

[This](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/802) might help regarding that

- Set the Viewport

This is another easy way that helps, you need to adjust the viewport to a standard size.

```
await page.setViewport({
  width: 1366,
  height: 768,
});
```

Comment: I need help spoofing WebGL Vendor and Renderer but the link: https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/802 you provided didn't work. Can you show me an example please